# Is there a faster/more efficient alternative for finding a value's closest match from a list in M/PowerQuery other than recursion?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

first post on Stack Overflow. I'm trying to get some perspective on finding closest matched values from lists and table columns using Power Query.

So if you have a list of {1.1, 3.2, 4.5, 6.6, 7.8} and you are looking for "4.6", then "4.5" is returned.

There apparently are no native functions in Power Query which do what I need. I've looked around for a script but the approaches which produce the desired outcome usually involve subtracting the lookup value from each value in a reference list, converting the results to absolute differences, and then returning the minimum. You have to do some extra steps to get the original value. The same technique is done on the DAX side of things too.

I'm looking to match say 1000+ values within a list of 50000+ values, so it can be quite time-consuming each time the query refreshes doing it the absolute difference way.

I searched around and couldn't find a binary search in M so I wrote the one below. It seems to work and improves performance immensely, but I wanted to know if there is a better approach anyone has found. I have read that using the List.Generate() function is preferable to recursion in M but do not understand why.

```
/*
Performs a binary search for a number within a sorted list
Function returns a number
*/
let
    funcLookup = (myList as list, myNum as number) =>
        let 
            n = List.Count(myList),
            n_2 = Number.RoundUp(n/2,0),  //Do not use Number.IntegerDivide()
        newDiffSign = Number.Sign(myNum - myList{n_2}), //Pos = 1, Neg = -1, Zero = 0 

        A =  if newDiffSign = 1 and n > 1 then  List.Range(myList, n_2, n-n_2) //Second half of the list
            else if newDiffSign = -1 and n > 1 then List.Range(myList, 0, n_2) //First half of the list
            else {myList{n_2}},                                                //Return the matched number, as a list 

//Recursively iterate to winnow the list to 1 number which will be the closest match
        Match = if n > 1 
            then @funcLookup(A, myNum)
            else myList{0}    
    in
        Match
in
funcLookup

-----
```

I call the above function using this:

```
listMyList = List.Buffer(List.Sort(MyTable[MyColumn])), //sorts and buffers the list in memory
MyNewTable = Table.AddColumn(MyTable, "Matched Value", each funcLookUp(listMyList, [MyColumn]))
```

Comment: If your list is sorted then it's difficult to beat binary search. If you sort both lists you could probably do something where you go through the list of targets (e.g. 0.7, 0.8., 0.85, etc.) and find all of the numbers closest to the first source number (1.1). Once you get past the midpoint between the first and second target, you switch to the second target and start tallying those.

Comment: The reason `List.Generate` is preferred to recursion is because the M/Power Query engine doesn't support tail-call optimization, so recursion can use lots of memory and easily result in a stack overflow. `List.Generate` is like a for-loop, so less memory is used.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
let
    Source = {1.1, 3.2, 4.5, 6.6, 7.8},
    SearchFor = 4.6,
    Search = let abs = List.Buffer(List.Transform( Source, (x)=> Number.Abs( x - SearchFor ) ) ) in Source{ List.PositionOf( abs, List.Min( abs ) ) }
in
    Search
```

Comment: Nice, but it still has to handle the subtraction and convert to absolute differences for each item in the list. I found that to be really time consuming when my datasets got large and I was doing a lot of reference lookups. Without the List.Buffer() function included the query would take ~5 mins to refresh. But the binary search was quicker than this way.

Answer (score -1):

Ohh, i'm fool. I don't read your post entirely. You can try that code. I'm not an author, but i think it's great.
P.S. Sorry that algoritm works for cohorts, but not for your problem.
P.P.S. It's the final version of code, works correctly and fast

```
     let
    TData = Table.FromList({3.2,7.5,8.6,2.3,9.3,4.4,1.1,5.6,6.7}, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"id"} ),
    TDataWrap = Table.AddColumn(Table.DuplicateColumn(TData, "id", "other"), "priority", each 1),
    TSearch = Table.AddColumn(Table.FromList({0.7,0.8,1,2.3,2.1,5.4,9.7,0}, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"id"}), "priority", each 0),
    merged = TDataWrap & TSearch,
    setOrder = Table.Sort(merged,{{"id", Order.Ascending}, {"priority", Order.Ascending}}),
    addForDown = Table.AddColumn(setOrder, "down", each if [priority] = 1 then [other] else null),
    fillDown = Table.FillDown(addForDown,{"down"}),
    addForUp =  Table.AddColumn(fillDown, "up", each if [priority] = 1 then [other] else null),
    fillUp = Table.FillUp(addForUp, {"up"}),
    preResult = Table.AddColumn(fillUp, "base", each if [down] = null then [up] else if [up] = null then [down] else 
        if Number.Abs([up] - [id]) > Number.Abs([down] - [id]) then [down] else [up]),
    FilteredRows = Table.SelectRows(preResult, each ([priority] = 0)),
    RemovedColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(FilteredRows,{"other", "priority", "down", "up"})
in
    RemovedColumns
```

Comment: Please don't use answer section for discussions